# save in zend is throwing a weird error

Tags: php, zend-framework

So I have come to the conclusion that this error is because of two specific line of code.

```
$notification_object->flag = true;
$notification_object->save();
```

seems to throw:

```
SQLSTATE[08P01]: <<Unknown error>>: 7 ERROR:  bind message supplies 0 parameters, but prepared statement "pdo_stmt_0000000f" requires 1
```

Does any one know why?

**More Info As Requested**

So how is $notifications_object created?

```
$notifications_table = new Users_Model_NotificationsMapper();
$notifications = $notifications_table->findByUserAndId($request, $identity->id);
```

then we loop through:

```
foreach($notifications as $notification_object){
    //Do some code

   //We need to now update a value in the database,
   //essentially in the row we just got back.

   $notifications_object->flag = true;
   $notifications_object->save();

}
```

Comment: You'll have to provide some more detail on the composition of your notification_object model.

Comment: Updated to explain how the object is created

Comment: Sorry, you'll need to provide a little more.  Can you show the notification_object class?  The way it's instantiated doesn't really help if we can't see what it does.

Comment: Since you're asking about an SQL error message, showing some SQL would help. Set `log_statement = 'all'` then re-run the test, and post the last few lines of the PostgreSQL log file up and including the error.